# MongooseJS - Return query after performing a count followed by a find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I would like to get the number of objects in a Collection and then use that number to perform a find. The code currently looks like this:

```
function() {
  TestModel.count({}, function(err, num) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err, undefined);
    }

    options.skip = Math.max(0, Math.floor((num - limit) * Math.random()));
    options.limit = limit;

    TestModel.find(conditions, fields, options).exec(callback);
  });
}
```

Where `testModel` is a mongoose model. And this works great! However, I would like to also be able to return the entire query (including `count`) pre-execution if `callback` above is null so that users can append more options to the pipeline (e.g. populate). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is `_this`?  Is it a Mongoose model?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that - let me edit the question to make that clearer.

Comment: What do you mean by the "(inlcuding `count`)" part of "return the entire query (including `count`)" pre-execution?  Do you mean the `num` result of the `count` query?

Comment: Given the above implementation, I need the result from count to run my find query. What I want is to be able to return an executable query from the scope of `function`, so I want to not execute count immediately either (since it's asynchronous).

Comment: I don't see a way to get that to work.  Probably better to always use a callback and have the caller use [`Model.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) to populate references in the result docs as needed.